# Remove trailing slash in DNN

Tags: angular, dotnetnuke

I have an angular app on a page loaded in DotNetNuke.
As you know DNN puts a trailing slash at the end of URL like `localhost/MyPage/`, while I'm using Angular routing with `html5mode(false)` when opening the page the URL becomes like `localhost/MyPage/#/` this cause a `404 Error` for the templates I want to use.

when I remove the slash at the end (`localhost/MyPage#/`) the problem is solved. the question is How can I tell DNN to not to put slash after URL?

Comment: In all my DNN installations, a trailing slash is never added to the url. Are you sure DNN is adding it?

Answer (score 1):

if you use dnn and routing, I have found usefull to use #

Usually I insert in Angular **useHash: true**:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
```

Let me know

Matteo